# bash `read -t` doesn't work on pipe

Tags: linux, bash, shell

A very simple way to demonstrate this is to run

```
mkfifo /tmp/a
read -t 1 a < /tmp/a
```

the read never return.

> Bash Manual says:
>   This option is only effective if
>   read is reading input from a terminal, pipe, or other special file;
>   it has no effect when reading from regular files

but /tmp/a is a pipe, output of ls is

```
ls -l /tmp/a
prw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Feb  4 22:18 /tmp/a
```

the bash version is:

> GNU bash, version 4.3.46(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
>   Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

the OS is:

```
Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my detailed answer on [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/352512/203203).

TL;DR: your `-t` flag does not seem to work because `read` is even not executed since *this is your shell that is blocked*, not your command.

---

Before executing your `read` command, `bash` tries to open `/tmp/a` and this is a blocking operation. Opening a named pipe for reading blocks until someone else opens it for writing.

You can check this with an erroneous command:

```
mkfifo my_fifo
a_command_that_does_not_exist < my_fifo
```

(your shell is blocked until someone opens `my_fifo` for writing, and only then will it tell you `command not found`)

Solution: `read -t 1 a <> /tmp/a`

(more on [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/352512/203203))

Answer (score 1):

When you read from the pipe, there needs to be someone writing to the pipe as well. "pipe" is just a communication mechanism. It doesn't "generate" any input by itself; it'll just pass the its input to its output end. It appears that you are just reading but there's no one writing to `/tmp/a`.

When `read` waits for input do `echo hello > /tmp/a` from another terminal and you'll see that `read` returns and `a` has the value "hello".

Read about pipes in detail here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html

Comment: when I excute: strace bash -c "read -t 3 a < /tmp/a", I found that read block at open("/tmp/a", O_RDONLY, So -t only work when somebody has open the pipe?

Comment: got it, thanks very much. finally I use: timeout 3 bash -c "read a </tmp/a" instead.

Comment: `read` is simply blocked until someone writes to it. `timeout` doesn't change much. It simply stops `read` from further wait. But the *real* issue is that no one is writing to the pipe. You may want to read the manual linked to understand how pipes work.

Comment: @P.P No, `read` is not blocked because this is not read that does the `open` in the `strace` output above. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just confirm that timeout does not work on a pipe stream because of a race condition. The sub-shell is executing the `read` statement before the input is made available.

Running:

```sh
echo 'hello' | {
 if read -t0
   then echo 'Input is available.'
   else echo 'No input available on the FD.'
 fi
}
```

Outputs:

```
No input available on the FD.
```

Introducing a dummy `:` NOP command ( or `wait 1` ) before the `read`, can change the deal:

```sh
echo 'hello' | {
 :
 if read -t0
   then echo 'Input is available.'
   else echo 'No input available on the FD.'
 fi
}
```

Then suddenly:

```
Input is available.
```

Comment: This race condition is an interesting fact. Just a rectification on your wording: timeout **does** work on a pipe stream (try `-t0.1`), this is `-t0` the problem here: it may or may not work because after bash forks, nothing guarantees that child1, on the left of the `|`, will be executed before child2, on the right. This is not the issue OP is having BTW.

Comment: Bash man page and `read` help explicitly mentions `-t 0` as `If TIMEOUT is 0, read returns immediately, without trying to read any data, returning success only if input is available on the specified file descriptor.` so that if you only want to check availability but not read the actual data, you have to use `-t0` and not `-t0.1`.

Comment: I was only reacting on your "timeout does not work on a pipe" and showing you it does.